# Colouring the console windows with rgb

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm new to C++. I am searching for new functions and I found `windows.h` functions interesting but difficult! I use `SetConsoleTextAttribute(Get---------, **value**)*;`

In place of **value** I'm putting definite colour values like 0-15 for solid definite colours and it is boring; I heard about shades and colour combinations as rbg. Can I use it in above command? If not then how to get started with these kind of colours? Specifically for Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: The console interface is very old and crude. I don't think you can use arbitrary RGB colors in it; certainly you can't with `SetConsoleTextAttribute`. The window functions are much more capable but unfortunately much harder to learn as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetConsoleTextAttribute only works with 16 bit color, there are just some predefined attributes as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes). Of course you can mix these attributes, but you can not use the RGB color space with this function.

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
```

If you wish to use the RGB color space, you should use the **SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx** function. The CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX struct has an attribute named ColorTable which is an array of type COLORREF. Use can use the RGB macro which is also defined in the standard Windows header to create your RGB color. Notice that this function works only on Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008 or higher.

Comment: Thnks can you give syntax too?? as i told you i'm new on most of sites i can't understand a word they say! spcially how to initiate COLORREF and give parameters to it??

Comment: Well as a matter of fact i found it's code!!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502865/how-to-set-entire-console-window-background-color-with-given-rgbsetconsolescree

Thanks for your support..!!